# React state not giving correct value on useEffect()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I'm trying to build a factorization algorithm using react. **I would like to add `results` to `LocalStorage` based on results from factorization**. However, `LocalStorage` sets previous results not current ones.

I think this is happening because `useEffect` runs on every new `[number]` (=user input) and not based on `[results]`. However, I need `useEffect` to run on new user input submition because that's when factorization has to be triggered.

How could I make `localStorage` set correct results after that factorization has completed (on the `finally` block if possible) ?

```js
const [results, setResults] = useState({
  default: [],
  detailed: [],
  isPrime: '',
});

const { number } = props

useEffect(() => {
  handleWorker(number);
  //accessing results here will give previous results
}, [number]);

const handleWorker = number => {
  try {
    const worker = new Worker(new URL('facto.js', import.meta.url));
    worker.postMessage({ number, algorithm });
    worker.onmessage = ({ data: { facto } }) => {
      setResults({ ...facto });
      //the worker 'streams live' results and updates them on setResults
    };
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error.message)
  } finally {
    localStorage.setItem(number, results)
    //here, results is not current state but previous one
  }
};
```

*Please note that everything else works fine*

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the previous value because `localStorage.setItem` is executed before `setResults` updates the state. Yo can do some refactor to make it work:

```
const [results, setResults] = useState({
  default: [],
  detailed: [],
  isPrime: '',
});

const { number } = props;
const workerRef = useRef(new Worker(new URL('facto.js', import.meta.url)));
const worker = workerRef.current;

useEffect(()=> {
    //-> create the listener just once
    worker.onmessage = ({ data: { facto } }) => {
      setResults({ ...facto }); 
    };
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
   //-> send message if number changed
   worker.postMessage({ number, algorithm });
}, [number]);

useEffect(() => {
   //-> update localStorage if results changed
   localStorage.setItem(number, results)
}, [results]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need (probably):

```
const [results, setResults] = useState({ /* YOUR STATE */ });

const { number } = props

const handleWorker = useCallback((number) => {
  // DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO HERE
},[]); // IF YOU DEPEND ON ANY MUTABLE VARIABLES, ADD THEM TO THE DEPENDENCY ARRAY

useEffect(() => {
  // DO WHATEVER YOU NEED TO DO HERE
  // INSTEAD OF localStorage.setItem(number, results)
  // DO localStorage.setItem(number, { ...facto })
}, [number,handleWorker]);
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Setting localStorage in the `try` block would not be very efficient since, as I mentionned, worker streams live results. localStorage would set many times the same number but with different results. It would be nice to have localStorage set results at the end only

Answer (score -1):

I think you can pass in the result state as dependent for the useEffect, so whenever the value of the result change , useEffect runs

```
useEffect(() => { //code goes here}, [results]);
```

Let say results also depends on a function handleWorker

```
useEffect(() => { //code goes here},
    [results,handleWorker]);
```

Comment: Since you will be using handleworker in the useEffect Function, you have to add it as a dependency, so whenever the result changes the useEffect function runs.
Handle Worker is declared outside of the useEffect function